# Module not Found: zipline import

Tags: python, module, zipline

Getting the following stack trace from line:

```
zipline/zipline/__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
    import numpy as np
ImportError: No module named 'numpy'
```

however, when I check `pip list`

```
pip list | grep numpy
DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 will reach the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 won't be maintained after that date. A future version of pip will drop support for Python 2.7. More details about Python 2 support in pip, can be found at https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/development/release-process/#python-2-support
numpy             1.16.6
```

This all occurs after I clone into the [Quantopian/Zipline Github Repo](https://github.com/quantopian/zipline).
I opened an [issue](https://github.com/quantopian/zipline/issues/2672) on github, after this edit I'll search SO for anything obvious I missed.

#### **Environment**

WSL Ubunut Subsystem

Pyhon 3.5.5

Bitness: 64

installed dependencies via
`sudo apt-get install libatlas-base-dev python-dev gfortran pkg-config libfreetype6-dev`

#### **Pip list**

```
alembic           1.4.2
asn1crypto        0.24.0
bcolz             0.12.1
Bottleneck        1.3.2
certifi           2019.11.28
chardet           3.0.4
click             7.1.1
contextlib2       0.6.0.post1
cycler            0.10.0
cyordereddict     1.0.0
Cython            0.29.15
decorator         4.4.2
empyrical         0.5.3
enum34            1.1.6
funcsigs          1.0.2
idna              2.6
intervaltree      3.0.2
ipaddress         1.0.17
itable            0.0.1
keyring           10.6.0
Logbook           1.5.3
lru-dict          1.1.6
lxml              4.5.0
Mako              1.1.2
MarkupSafe        1.1.1
matplotlib        2.2.4
mercurial         4.5.3
mock              3.0.5
multipledispatch  0.6.0
networkx          1.11
numexpr           2.7.1
numpy             1.16.6
pandas            0.22.0
pandas-datareader 0.8.1
patsy             0.5.1
pinkfish          0.5.1
pip               19.3.1
pycrypto          2.6.1
pygobject         3.26.1
python-dateutil   2.8.1
python-editor     1.0.4
pytz              2019.3
pyxdg             0.25
requests          2.22.0
requests-file     1.4.3
scipy             1.2.2
SecretStorage     2.3.1
setuptools        39.0.1
six               1.14.0
sortedcontainers  2.1.0
SQLAlchemy        1.3.15
statsmodels       0.11.0
tables            3.5.2
toolz             0.10.0
trading-calendars 1.11.5
urllib3           1.25.7
wheel             0.30.0
zipline           1.3.0
WARNING: You are using pip version 19.3.1; however, version 20.0.2 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

## **Update**

running as a script, `sudo python test.py` returns

```
File "test.py", line 1, in <module>
    import zipline
  File "../zipline/zipline/__init__.py", line 29, in <module>
    from .utils.run_algo import run_algorithm
  File "../zipline/zipline/utils/run_algo.py", line 17, in <module>
    from zipline.data import bundles
  File "../zipline/zipline/data/bundles/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from . import quandl  # noqa
  File "../zipline/zipline/data/bundles/quandl.py", line 17, in <module>
    from . import core as bundles
  File "../zipline/zipline/data/bundles/core.py", line 14, in <module>
    from ..adjustments import SQLiteAdjustmentReader, SQLiteAdjustmentWriter
  File "../zipline/zipline/data/adjustments.py", line 24, in <module>
    from ._adjustments import load_adjustments_from_sqlite
ImportError: No module named _adjustments
```

Comment: Have you tried `pip install trading-calendars`?

Comment: @FlyingTeller Yes, the module cannot be found/is unavailable through pip

Comment: It's [on PyPi](https://pypi.org/project/trading-calendars/), don't know why your pip claims to not be able to find it. You can download and install it from  [github](https://github.com/quantopian/trading_calendars) though

Comment: @FlyingTeller I figured it, thank you for the assist though

Comment: Nevermind, just saw that the PyPi version goes only to Python 3.5. But you can still install manually

Comment: @FlyingTeller yes it looks like manual is going to be the fix. I'll edit the question because now I'm having setup.py issues :))))

Comment: Hi Dan, have you tried using conda? The easiest and best supported way is through conda http://www.zipline.io/install.html#windows as Zipline has several C dependencies.

Comment: @freddiev4 I switched to WSL Ubuntu flavor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue arose due to the presence of [multiple versions of python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2812520/dealing-with-multiple-python-versions-and-pip). Using the `python -m pip install <packages>` command inside of the `zipline/zipline` repo, I was able to successful execute `import zipline` inside a python shell